# Magento 1.9: frontend pages are blank (only header is visible)

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I am new to Magento, We have one Magento 1.9 version website. Actually I want to change the host, for this, I took all files backup from the server and also exported the database and then I have uploaded all files into another host(Godaddy) and imported the database. Everything working fine at the admin panel or backend pages, but front end pages not loading properly, just its loading header part of the page.

I didn't change anything in the files, I just transferred the files from one host into another hosting, but I don't know why frontend pages are not loading.

Please anyone give me a solution to fix that issue. Please see the below screenshot for reference. Thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This behavior could be due to a PHP error that is not being printed to the screen because of the PHP configuration. Try enabling print error on PHP and see if anything shows up. Contact your provider (Godaddy) for guidance.

Also, ensure that all configuration on admin panel is set. When you upload database and make a new installation, even when uploading the old database, if you do not specify the same old encryption key, some configuration will be missing, for example payment provider tokens and so on.

Check also if your home page CMS still exists and is configured to show on home page. Check this on CMS pages and maybe on your theme configuration.

```
system -> configuration -> general -> web -> homepage CMS
```

For any further guidance, would need more details.